# python, how to convert a pandas series into a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas series sf:

```
email
email1@email.com    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
email2@email.com    [2.0, 0.0, 0.0]
email3@email.com    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
email4@email.com    [4.0, 0.0, 0.0]
email5@email.com    [1.0, 0.0, 3.0]
email6@email.com    [1.0, 5.0, 0.0]
```

How can I convert it to this following pandas DataFrame:

```
index | email
________________________
0     | email1@email.com
1     | email2@email.com
2     | email3@email.com
3     | email4@email.com
4     | email5@email.com
5     | email6@email.com
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> s = p.Series(data=[[1.0,  0.0,  0.0],[2.0,  0.0,  0.0]],
                 index=['email1@email.com','email2@email.com'])
>>> s
email1@email.com    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
email2@email.com    [2.0, 0.0, 0.0]
dtype: object


>>> df = p.DataFrame(data=s.index, columns=['email'])
>>> df
              email
0  email1@email.com
1  email2@email.com
```