# Split Pandas Series into DataFrame by delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, series

I'm trying to split a `pandas` `series` object by a particular delimiter `"; "` in this case. I want to turn it into a `dataframe` there will always be the same amount of "columns" or to be more exact, same amount of `"; "` that will indicate columns.  I thought this would do the trick but it didnt [python, how to convert a pandas series into a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022172/python-how-to-convert-a-pandas-series-into-a-pandas-dataframe) I dont want to iterate through, I'm sure `pandas` has made a shortcut that's more effective.

**Does anyone know of the most efficient way to split this series into a dataframe by `"; "` ?**

```
#Example Data
SR_test = pd.Series(["a; b; c; d; e","aa; bb; cc; dd; ee","a1; b2; c3; d4; e5"])
# print(SR_test)
# 0         a; b; c; d; e
# 1    aa; bb; cc; dd; ee
# 2    a1; b2; c3; d4; e5

#Convert each row one at a time (not efficient)
tmp = []
for element in SR_test:
    tmp.append([e.strip() for e in element.split("; ")])
DF_split = pd.DataFrame(tmp)
# print(DF_split)
#     0   1   2   3   4
# 0   a   b   c   d   e
# 1  aa  bb  cc  dd  ee
# 2  a1  b2  c3  d4  e5
```

Comment: EdChum and Jezrael, who answered first? I want to be fair. These are great answers, exactly what I was going for.

Comment: I think I was first, but difference was only about `15 seconds`. So I dont know if it is important. @EdChum, what do you think?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = SR_test.str.split('; ', expand=True)
print df

    0   1   2   3   4
0   a   b   c   d   e
1  aa  bb  cc  dd  ee
2  a1  b2  c3  d4  e5
```

Another faster solution, if `Series` have no `NaN` values:

```
print pd.DataFrame([ x.split('; ') for x in SR_test.tolist() ])
    0   1   2   3   4
0   a   b   c   d   e
1  aa  bb  cc  dd  ee
2  a1  b2  c3  d4  e5
```

**Timings**:

```
SR_test = pd.concat([SR_test]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [21]: %timeit SR_test.str.split('; ', expand=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 34.5 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([ x.split('; ') for x in SR_test.tolist() ])
100 loops, best of 3: 9.59 ms per loop
```

Comment: Iterating through is quicker?

Comment: Yes, if If use this way. str.split is a bit slower, because it works with NaN values very nice too.

Answer (score 3):

Use the vectorised [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with param `expand=True` and pass as the data arg to the `DataFrame` ctor:

```
In [4]:
df = pd.DataFrame(SR_test.str.split(';',expand=True))
df

Out[4]:
    0    1    2    3    4
0   a    b    c    d    e
1  aa   bb   cc   dd   ee
2  a1   b2   c3   d4   e5
```